# Controll cube with arduino + mpu6050

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, motion-capture

So i have an arduino with an mpu6050 attached to it. It is currently set up to send the raw data from the imu sensor to my computer.

I would like to use this data to control a cube in blender with inside the blender game engine, in realtime.

My problem is that i cant figure out how to get blender to read the data from the mpu. Im pretty new to python.

Pyserial seems to work and blender connects to the arduino, but the actual code on how to get the IMU sensor data into blender is still a mystery to me.

Update: I can now move the cube with the IMU sensor, so blender is reading the data. Even tho the motion is coming trough the movement is not very accurate and that someting I will have to work on.

Here is a link to my github with the arduino firmware and blend file:
https://github.com/Bjaza/mpu6050Arduino-blender

to be more precise heres a video of what i'm trying to do inside blender:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bl_8xg2DdJ4

the blender scene im using is only a cube parented to a bone with an allways sensor and a python controller

the arduino is using the standard mpu6050 libraries.

If anyone has any suggestions on what kind of python script to use in blender, i would be ever so grateful.

Posted similar question in arduino forum and the anwser was to match the data input format to the read format. 
Example: from this 0.00/0.00/0.00 to this 0.00,0.00,0.00

Comment: I suppose you are able to get some data into Blender and you are trying to move a Cube. Please post example of the real-time data you are getting and how you are getting it - in `app.handler` perhaps? Maybe post the scene you are using for testing? We can help you with moving the Cube, that is not hard, but it is hard to guess what you need exactly.

Comment: Oh, so the issue is the data transfer. On blender side, you get bits from serial port like `data = ser.readline()` or `data = ser.read(bytesToRead)` in some kind of loop. But it takes 2 to communicate, without knowing what the Arduino is sending, it is hard to guess how to handle the incoming stream and how to chop it into coordinates. The serial communication stuff is not very related to Blender, you might get better help in Arduino or RaspberryPi stackexchange.

Comment: The error says the provided string is not sufficient for build-in parsing (string to float). I suggest you create an own parser that can parse the provided format and extract the data you want.

Comment: the code doens't work with me can anybody help ?? i don't want it to be complicated i just want simple cube to rotate many errors appeared in the console